# Code to set up Print Area won't work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new to VBA and Excel.
I have a code that sets up the Print Area for a document

```
Dim count As Integer
count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("E106").Value

    Dim i As Integer
    i = count + 4


    Sheets("sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(35, i))
    End Sub
```

But when I go into Print Preview, the full sheet is displayed. Sheet1 and sheet2 are aliases for the worksheet names, but I have other code that references them and it works just fine. I already tried recording the Macro to set the print area in the first place, then inserted my custom range.
Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Record a macro, set the print area, and then view the macro source for an example of doing it.

Comment: Hi Ken, that's exactly what I did, then I changed the range to my custom one, but it doesn't work

Comment: Then it would seem that the range you're setting isn't correct, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PrintArea` Property of the `PageSetup` is not an object (`range`) but a `string` holding the *address* of the desired range. Try this:

```
With Sheets("sheet1")
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(35, i)).Address
End With             '                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more advanced version (tested):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("offset(B3,0,0,32,Sheet2!E106+2)").Address
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False   ' optional to hide the print area rectangle
End With
```

Comment: This is a nice and useful shortcut, I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @A.S.H I think someone assumed that it looks too similar to yours or that it is incorrect because of the unusual offset function. I will leave it anyway

Comment: I think you should leave it, the method although unusual is very useful for pros ;)